# Troubles connecting Azure App Service to a Bitnami Mongo ReplicaSet through Network Peering

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-envrmnt

As per the title, I have 2 different resource groups:

- App Service running 2 containers with our Node application. It has no VNet configured by default. Let's call it **AS** from now on.
- MongoDB ReplicaSet by Bitnami, containing 2 instances. It has a VNet configured by default: address space `10.0.0.0/24`, with instances having assigned addresses `10.0.0.4` and `10.0.0.5`. Let's call it **DB** from now on.

I wanted to create a network peering in order to let App Service Plan talking with Databases. Since AS hasn't a VNet, I had firstly to create one. Here is the network topology **before** the peering:

- AS: address space `10.1.0.0/24`
- DB: address space `10.0.0.0/24`

I then created the peering `AS => DB`, so far so good. Azure Portal display the networks as an unique one, with flag "Connected". Also, the App Service Plan's Virtual Network Integration interface looks good. If you look at the bottom of the image, you'll see as *Address routed to Vnet* the DB's address space, that is `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.255`.

[image]
Despite the network peering seems configured correctly, my Node applications still can't connect to the databases. I got mainly two errors application-side so far:

- [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.0.0.5:27017]
- [MongoError: connect EACCES 10.0.0.5:27017]

whereas Azure Container's `tcpping` gives me either:

- An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 10.0.0.5:27017
- Connection timed out

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a route pointing back to the point to site address space from the 2nd VNET? (e.g. `192.168.0.0/24` via `1st VNET`). I don't believe the VNET peering will tell the 2nd VNET about the point to site address space by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a route pointing back to the point to site address space from the 2nd VNET? I don't believe the VNET peering will tell the 2nd VNET about the point to site address space by default.

There are some checkboxes in the VNET peering configuration which are a bit shady in their description, here's what works, meaning what will add that route for you:

[image: VNET peering with point-to-site address space]

Restart the Web App after you make the changes, give it a few seconds and test with `tcpping`. There's probably some BGP in this mix, so if it doesn't work right away just give it a minute.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I am close to get it working. `tcpping` is now failing with a different error: `The requested address is not valid in its context`. Any idea?

Comment: I never saw that. Restart the Web App a 2nd time? Maybe remove and redo the VNET integration from the Portal UI (Web App > Network)?